# How do I get results (successful/not successful) from a g:uploadForm in a GSP file?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to get the results from a g:uploadForm action I have in my GSP file. I need to upload the file, then after it's successfully uploaded I need to tell if the upload was successful, then display another area in the GSP file.

```
            <g:uploadForm action="save" method="post">
            <h1>
                <g:message code="upload"/>
            </h1>
            <h5>
                <g:message code="upload.message"/>
            </h5>
            <br/>
            <input type="file" id="Upload" name="Upload" class="input"/>
            <br/>
            <g:formButton type="submit" buttonClass="btn-primary btn-lg" buttonTextCode="upload.button" />
            </g:uploadForm>
```

I just need something to say if it was successful or not.

Is this something I need to handle in the controller and just post to the GSP after that? I'm new to grails and groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty common to use `flash` scoped variables for these types of messages. In fact, if you look at the Grails documentation about [uploading files](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles) you will see it does just that.

```
def upload() {
    def f = request.getFile('myFile')
    if (f.empty) {
        flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
        render(view: 'uploadForm')
        return
    }
    f.transferTo(new File('/some/local/dir/myfile.txt'))
    redirect(render: 'uploadForm')
}
```

Using the above example you could then include the following in your `uploadForm` GSP page.

`${flash.message}` to display this.

Comment: Thanks Josh! I'm new to grails and groovy, so this example really helped. I think I get it now.